# Fast copy array to array

Tags: c++, arrays

Im try to make my real-time video streaming app.

Right now, im try to speed up my application.

And i have such question:

How to speed up "for" loop here:

```
        boost::array<uchar, 30000> RECV_DATA; // array for receive all data from socket

        size_t ImageSize = image_recver.read_some(
            boost::asio::buffer(RECV_DATA), ignored_error); // complete image size

        vector<uchar> Img (ImageSize); // the new array, will contains only image data

        for (int i = 0; i < ImageSize; i++) {
            Img[i] = RECV_DATA[i]; // Image array filling
        }
```

Comment: unclear why you need `RECV_DATA` at all. why dont you write the received data directly to `Img` ?

Comment: @user463035818, because after that the image will be displayed in opencv "imshow" and without "cleaning the array" imshow just does not work :c

Comment: sorry I dont know what "does not work" means and I lost my dictionary :P. Seriously, maybe we have a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here and maybe you better show the code with your actual problem and explain what doesnt work...or maybe the given answer already has what you need to fix it

Comment: @user463035818, thanks for comments. Anyway, solution was found (below). If you realy interested, without "clearing" im was getting just black image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::vector` range constructor to copy `RECV_DATA`:

```
std::vector<uchar> Img(RECV_DATA.begin(), RECV_DATA.begin() + ImageSize);
```

Or, better, read directly into `std::vector<uchar>`:

```
std::vector<uchar> RECV_DATA(image_recver.available());
size_t imageSize = image_recver.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(RECV_DATA), ignored_error);
RECV_DATA.resize(imageSize);
```